# NodeJS server doesn't start with pm2

Tags: node.js, node-modules, pm2, npm-scripts, npm-start

When I'm trying to start my nodeJS-server with pm2 it stops or returns an error.

Here's the relevant package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon --watch '**/*.ts' --exec ts-node index.ts",
"bundle-colyseus-client": "browserify ./node_modules/colyseus.js/lib/index.js -s Colyseus -o static/colyseus.js",
"build": "npm run bundle-colyseus-client",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"}
```

I tried the following commands to start the server:

- `pm2 start npm -- start` [STOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pACMY.png)
- `pm2 start index.ts`
  [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBvuS.png)

Answer (score 1):

you trying to run ts file with ts-node.
try to install typescript in pm2

`pm2 install typescript`

and then the second command

`pm2 start index.ts`

Comment: Still same issue attached the screenshot below.
https://snag.gy/x0eVCK.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PM2 as a module, the documentation says to add the following script on your `package.json` start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
},
```

Now you can restart your application.
Source: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/integration/heroku/#add-pm2-as-a-module

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this solves the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. For some reason Heroku don't work with the simple start of PM2. Added the documentation guide to run PM2 on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

your server might be running with nodemon i think
first stop your server by quit from nodemon then start pm2 
it should work then

Comment: now server is running without nodemon but still same issue.
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "bundle-colyseus-client": "browserify ./node_modules/colyseus.js/lib/index.js -s Colyseus -o static/colyseus.js",
    "build": "npm run bundle-colyseus-client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },

Comment: Still same issue attached the screenshot below.
https://snag.gy/x0eVCK.jpg